# NodeJS not responding on AJAX post

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express, routes

I' am using NodeJS/Express in combination with a jquery on the client side. On the client side  i wan't to send a json object to NodeJS/Express server for futher handling. But instead i got the following message in the logging of Node:

```
POST /BusinessRules/findApiData 500 43.905 ms - 151
```

What i expect is a the message "Hello World" from function exports.findApiData in the index.js.

Please can you help me to understand and fix this problem!

On the NodeJS server i use the following files:

- Router.js (for setup the routes, here in is also calling the function within the index.js)
- App.js    (configuration)
- BusinessRules/index.js  (handling request page requests)

**On the Client side:**

```
function getNewValue(t,e){

 if (e.keyCode == 13){
   newValue =  '{"_id": "' + id + '","' + $th + '": "' + t.ltrim() + "}';
   var jsonNewValue = JSON.parse(newValue);
   $.ajax({
           url:'/BusinessRules/findApiData',
           type:'POST',
           contentType: 'application/json',
                  data: jsonNewValue });
          }
 }
```

**Router.js**

```
  app.post('/BusinessRules/findApiData', require('./views/BusinessRules/index').findApiData);
```

**index.js [EDITED}**

```
'use strict'
exports.find = function(req, res, next){
    console.log("find");
    req.query.lookupValue = req.query.lookupValue ? req.query.lookupValue : '';
    req.query.limit = req.query.limit ? parseInt(req.query.limit, null) : 20;
    req.query.page = req.query.page ? parseInt(req.query.page, null) : 1;
    req.query.sort = req.query.sort ? req.query.sort : '_id';

    var filters = {};
    if (req.query.lookupValue) {
        filters.lookupValue = new RegExp('^.*?'+ req.query.lookupValue +'.*$', 'i');
    }

    req.app.db.models.BusinessRules.pagedFind({
        filters: filters,
        keys: 'lookupValue  tagCattegory  tagScore  typeBusinessRule  _id',
        limit: req.query.limit,
        page: req.query.page,
        sort: req.query.sort
    }, function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }

        if (req.xhr) {
            res.header("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
            results.filters = req.query;
            console.log("Results XHR ");
            res.send(results);
            res.json(results);
        }
        else {
            results.filters = req.query;
            //res.json(results);
            console.log("Results No XHR ");
            //console.log(results);
            res.render('BusinessRules/index', { data: results.data });


        }

    });
};

exports.read = function(req, res, next){
    req.app.db.models.BusinessRules.findById(req.params.id).exec(function(err, BusinessRules) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }

        if (req.xhr) {
            res.send(BusinessRules);
        }
        else {
            res.render('BusinessRules/details', { BusinessRules: BusinessRules });
        }
    });
};

exports.add = function(req, res){
    res.render('BusinessRules/add');
};

exports.create = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('START POST: ');
    var workflow = req.app.utility.workflow(req, res);

    workflow.on('validate', function() {
        console.log('START POST(1) IF FORM CHECK: ');
        if (!req.body.lstTypeBusinessRule) {
            workflow.outcome.errors.push('Please enter a TypeBusinessRule.');
            console.log('TypeBusinessRule niet gevuld');
            return workflow.emit('response');
        }
        workflow.emit('createBusinessRule');
    });

    workflow.on('createBusinessRule', function () {
        console.log('STAR POST (3):Worflow On:');
        var fieldsToSet = {
            typeBusinessRule: req.body.lstTypeBusinessRule,
            lookupValue: req.body.txtLookupValue,
            tagCattegory: req.body.txtTagCattegory,
            tagScore: req.body.txtTagScore,
            creationDate: Date()
        };
        console.log(fieldsToSet);

        req.app.db.models.BusinessRules.create(fieldsToSet, function(err, BusinessRule) {
            if (err) {
                return workflow.emit('exception', err);
            }

            workflow.outcome.record = BusinessRule;
           // req.flash('success','BusinessRule Added');
            res.location('/BusinessRules');
            res.redirect('/BusinessRules');
        });
    });
    workflow.emit('validate');
};

exports.findApiData = function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("Hallo Erik");
    res.send("Hello World");
};
```

**App.js [EDITED]**

```
'use strict';

//dependencies
var config = require('./config'),
    express = require('express'),
    cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    session = require('express-session'),
    mongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    helmet = require('helmet');
 //   csrf = require('csurf');

//create express app
var app = express();

//keep reference to config
app.config = config;

//setup the web server
app.server = http.createServer(app);

//setup mongoose
app.db = mongoose.createConnection(config.mongodb.uri);
app.db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'mongoose connection error: '));
app.db.once('open', function () {
  //and... we have a data store
});

//config data models
require('./models')(app, mongoose);

//settings
app.disable('x-powered-by');
app.set('port', config.port);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

//middleware
app.use(require('morgan')('dev'));
app.use(require('compression')());
app.use(require('serve-static')(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(require('method-override')());
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' })); // parse application/vnd.api+json as json
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser(config.cryptoKey));
app.use(session({
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  secret: config.cryptoKey,
  store: new mongoStore({ url: config.mongodb.uri })
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
//app.use(csrf({ cookie: { signed: true } }));
helmet(app);

//response locals
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 // res.cookie('_csrfToken', req.csrfToken());
  res.locals.user = {};
  res.locals.user.defaultReturnUrl = req.user && req.user.defaultReturnUrl();
  res.locals.user.username = req.user && req.user.username;
  next();
});

//global locals
app.locals.projectName = app.config.projectName;
app.locals.copyrightYear = new Date().getFullYear();
app.locals.copyrightName = app.config.companyName;
app.locals.cacheBreaker = 'br34k-01';

//setup passport
require('./passport')(app, passport);

//setup routes
require('./routes')(app, passport);

//custom (friendly) error handler
app.use(require('./views/http/index').http500);

//setup utilities
app.utility = {};
app.utility.sendmail = require('./util/sendmail');
app.utility.slugify = require('./util/slugify');
app.utility.workflow = require('./util/workflow');

//listen up
app.server.listen(app.config.port, function(){
  //and... we're live
  console.log('Server is running on port ' + config.port);
});
```

Comment: Your server sends no response to your `/BusinessRules/findApiData` route so it is to be expected that the client receives nothing back.  Are you saying you don't even see the `console.log()` on the server?  If you are expecting a client response, then you need a `res.send(...)` or `res.json(...)` or some sort of response in your route handler.

Comment: Why have you not responded to a clarifying question yet?  When you post a question, please hang around and check back several times to see if people are confused at all by your question and you can help clarify it.  Otherwise those people who came by to try to help will just be gone by the time you come back and answer their clarifying questions.  You are much more likely to get a timely answer if you are timely in responding to questions about your question.  That's just how this site works.  It's different than a forum where you drop the question off and come back the next day.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I tried to use res.send('Hello World'); But still i got no response

Comment: I think we need to see more of the code.  I don't even see where you're doing a `.listen()` to start the server properly.  Plus, you don't show where you actually use router.js or whether index.js is being loaded properly.  Basically, there's far too listen shown here for us to know where things are going wrong.  Are you seeing errors on the server side?

Comment: Thanks, i edited the post for more you to see more code. I get no errors or warnings and i see that the function is not called from the $AJAX call

Comment: Why don't you back way, way up and make the most simple possible server with Express, create one route and verify you can get that route called from your browser and get a result back in the browser.  Then, add all this other complexity one step at a time making sure things work each time you add something. There's so much going on here, I have no idea where the problem could be without the ability to debug and observe myself. Also, you've still not disclosed ANY code that loads router.js so I don't know why you'd expect that code to get called.  But, really, go back to something simple first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to the comments, i solved this issue by stringify the JSON object. I don't know why that is required. But it works.

```
function getNewValue(t,e){

 if (e.keyCode == 13){
   newValue =  '{"_id": "' + id + '","' + $th + '": "' + t.ltrim() + "}';
   var jsonNewValue = JSON.parse(newValue);
   $.ajax({
           url:'/BusinessRules/findApiData',
           type:'POST',
           contentType: 'application/json',
                  data: JSON.stringify(jsonNewValue)});
          }
 }
```